# WOPI file name with the special characters is not opening the file in the online editor

Tags: c#, ms-wopi, office-online-server

There is a WOPI client and host which are setup exclusively for one of the web application and the online editor is working smoothly when the file name is proper without any URL reserved characters, but when a file name contains +,#,& signs WOPI protocol routes are treating these characters as delimiters and provide 404 error as the route would not available for GetFile, GetFileInfo endpoints.

Example:

```
        [Route("files/{fileName}/")]
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<FileInfoBE> GetFileInfo(string fileName, string access_token)
        { //Logic here }
```

In the above endpoint call if a filename contains a plus(+) sign and if the call to this endpoint is URL encoded the plus sign will be converted to %2b, ideally it should hit the endpoint, but before the call is made by a webclient the %2b is getting converted to + sign and gives a 404 error.

Note: custom encoding is not helpful as the OWA server interacts with the WOPI service.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that route attribute parameters won't accept any reserved characters, **EVEN** when they are URL-encoded:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2

This **will work**:

https://localhost:44349/files/?fileName=mydocument%2B%23%26.docx&access_token=test-token

```
[Route("files/")]
[HttpGet]
public async Task<string> GetFileInfo2(string fileName, string access_token)
{
    return "Test";
}
```

This **won't** work:

https://localhost:44349/files/mydocument%2B%23%26.docx?access_token=test-token

```
[Route("files/{fileName}/")]
[HttpGet]
public async Task<string> GetFileInfo(string fileName, string access_token)
{
    return "Test";
}
```

Complete example from Javascript front end to C# back end with a WebClient proxy call:

Javascript:

```
let fileName = encodeURIComponent('mydocument+#&.docx');
fetch(`files?fileName=${fileName}&access_token=test-token`)
    .then(function (response) {
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(function (myJson) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(myJson));
    });
```

C#:

```
[Route("files/")]
[HttpGet]
public async Task<string> GetFileInfo(string fileName, string access_token)
{
    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
    {
        var host = $"{HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Scheme}://{HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host}:{HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Port}";

        var data = client.DownloadString($"{host}/proxy/files/?fileName={HttpUtility.UrlEncode(fileName)}&access_token={HttpUtility.UrlEncode(access_token)}");

        return data;
    }
}

[AllowAnonymous]
[Route("proxy/files/")]
[HttpGet]
public async Task<string> ProxyGetFileInfo(string fileName, string access_token)
{
    return "MyValues";

}
```

[image]

Why these characters are disallowed and why it needs to be handled in the first place:

Excluded US-ASCII Characters disallowed within the URI syntax:

```
   control     = <US-ASCII coded characters 00-1F and 7F hexadecimal>
   space       = <US-ASCII coded character 20 hexadecimal>
   delims      = "<" | ">" | "#" | "%" | <">
```

The character "#" is excluded because it is used to delimit a URI from a fragment identifier. The percent character "%" is excluded because it is used for the encoding of escaped characters. In other words, the "#" and "%" are reserved characters that must be used in a specific context.

List of unwise characters are allowed but may cause problems:

```
   unwise      = "{" | "}" | "|" | "\" | "^" | "[" | "]" | "`"
```

Characters that are [reserved](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.2) within a query component and/or have special meaning within a URI/URL:

```
  reserved    = ";" | "/" | "?" | ":" | "@" | "&" | "=" | "+" | "$" | ","
```

The "reserved" syntax class above refers to those characters that are allowed within a URI, but which may not be allowed within a particular component of the generic URI syntax. **Characters in the "reserved" set are not reserved in all contexts**. The hostname, for example, can contain an optional username so it could be something like `ftp://user@hostname/` where the '@' character has special meaning.

Source:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13500078/3850405

Comment: Since Microsoft office online OWA server handshakes with the WOPI service in a specific route format, The route controller/file with the parameters is not supported.Thanks for explaining the routing concept.

Comment: @MahantheshKumbar No problem! Please mark the answer as accepted if it helped you solve the question.